# Java DatagramSocket sending but not receiving

Tags: java, networking, datagram

I'm working on a game in Java, and I'm trying to communicate between a client and server on the same computer over the internet, and eventually between multiple computers.  I used to be able to, but now the server doesn't seem to be receiving any packets from the client.  I'll try to post all the relevant code.

This is on the server:

```
private DatagramSocket m_Socket = new DatagramSocket( 8000 );
private DatagramPacket m_DatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket( new byte[ 1024 ], 1024 );
```

...

```
while( true )
{
    m_Socket.receive( m_DatagramPacket );
    byte[] data = new byte[ 1024 ];
    data = m_DatagramPacket.getData( );
    System.out.println( "SERVER RECEIVING: " + data );
}
```

This is on the client:

```
private DatagramSocket m_Socket = new DatagramSocket( null );
private DatagramPacket m_DatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket( new byte[ 1024 ], 1024 );
```

...

```
m_DatagramPacket.setAddress( InetAddress.getByName( "72.49.50.49" ) );
m_DatagramPacket.setPort( 8000 );
m_DatagramPacket.setLength( length );
m_DatagramPacket.setData( data );

// "data" is the byte array, "length" is the length of the array

m_Socket.send( m_DatagramPacket );
```

I'm seeing the packet in Wireshark so I know it's sending.

EDIT: I may not understand how Wireshark works, is the screenshot below sending or receiving the packet?

Wireshark:
[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Firewall exception:
[image: Opening port 8000]

Port forwarding:
[image: Forwarded port 8000]

EDIT:
I also ran this port tester program to test port 8000 and it says the port is open
[image: Port tester]

UPDATE:
For some reason I guess our routers were just refusing connections from the source local IP to the external IP destination.  I can connect to the server using the local IP from the same network and using the external IP from a different network

Comment: So are you using the same port for both the client and server on the same machine?

Comment: "is the screenshot below sending or receiving the packet?" - it is sending from the from-address to the to-address shown. As you are sniffing the LAN connection, this is an outbound packet. Do you have a firewall rule that lets UDP traffic on port 8000 get *out?*

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No, the server is using 8000 and the client's port is assigned automatically.

Comment: @EJP I didn't know that firewalls blocked outgoing packets, so no I don't think I do have a rule for that

Comment: @EJP on second thought, wouldn't I need a rule to allow outbound traffic on the port that the client is assigned (61485 in the screenshot)

Comment: @JoeGoris It would be quicker to try it than to ask, don't you think? Unfortunately firewalls do have outbound port rules, although the security they add is zero. Just an inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah but I'd still like to be educated on the subject

Answer (score 0):

If your client side you are creating an unbounded `DatagramSocket` (By passing `null` to the `DatagramSocket(SocketAddress bindaddr)`) which means there will not be any originating port for that socket. Eventhough this might work, this is clearly not the correct approach. In your client side you must do the following change.

```
private DatagramSocket m_Socket = new DatagramSocket();
private DatagramPacket m_DatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket( new byte[ 1024 ], 1024 );
```

Using the Default `DatagramSocket` constructor will bind the socket to next available port and will guarantee that there is a source port involved in the communication.

And your firewall exception doesn't have a Source IP and Source Port pattern or restriction. Please check based on your Router whether this is required.

Comment: I forget why I passed null in the constructor, but I have removed it now.  As for the firewall exception, the source IP and source ports are not required.  Thanks for the tips, but they do not solve my problem

Comment: Good. But you must be aware that UDP is unreliable and there is a possibility that your packets you send from client are never recieved by the server. So you must implement a packet re-sending mechanism. Sort of an Application Level Protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll work on that after I solve my problem

Comment: An unbound socket is bound when you first send from it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, assuming that your IP and other codes you write but not in above is correct,I have done a lot of test, even tried to change the settings of the firewall.But it still works.
So, I think that maybe because of the unreliability of UDP protocol, your server sometimes can not receive the data from the client.You can just try to use TCP protocol.

Secondly, in your screenshot of PcWinTech.com v3.0.0 , it seems that your computer is in the subnetwork. So I gust that maybe the IP("72.49.50.49") is your router's IP, and I suggest you to check the settings of the router whether the router can transmit the data to your computer ,say, port forwarding.And I have just find a [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) that may help you.

Comment: wasn't me... anyway I also tried port forwarding but I'll read the article for more info

Comment: Probably because you don't provide a concrete answer but rather a list of assumptions and recommendations; things typically better as comments. Not the -1 either.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yeah,,,may be you are right. I have been thinking about this question for all morning, doing a lot of test. But finally I can just get this two assumptions...Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JoeBoris after trying port forwarding ,can it still not work?Maybe you can try to run your server and client program in the same subnetwork at first, in order to check if there is something wrong with the existing code.

Comment: @JoeBoris if it still can not receive the data, please send your code to me...because I really wanna to work out this problem ...and my email can be:whbfcc@126.com

Comment: Even after port forwarding, the packet is still not received by the server.  I will send you my whole game but my code is somewhat complex and I simplified it a lot for the OP. Also my naming conventions are not very standard so it might take a while to understand

Comment: @JoeBoris OK.Code simplification will be better.I am looking forward to email.

Comment: Do you think the downvote could be because you start your answer by saying you don't know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old Question But the answer is really simple,

make the client create a request:

Client UDP ----- data Request ----> to server
the server is receiving with `DatagramPacket`,

after a client make a request, you can send the data using client's address and port,

Example:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[20];

DatagramPacket receive = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, InetAddress.getByName(ADDRESS), PORT);
socket.receive(receive); // the server will wait to a client to connect
```

lets say the client sent `Hello server`
after that you could just do (the endpoint is for the client):

```
DatagramPacket sendData = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, receive.getAddress(), receive.getPort());
socket.send(sendData)
```